# How can I check which version of Riak I am running?

Tags: riak

I have Riak installed on my machine and it's running (`riak ping` returns 'pong').

How can I check which version of Riak I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ riak version
```

appears to be the way.

`riak_kv_version` is not the same thing as `riak version`.  See:

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2016-April/018319.html

Answer (score 9):

`riak ping` to ensure your node is running, then:

`riak-admin status | grep riak_kv_version`